# ng-dialog not showing content of template in popup window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want  to create a pop up on click on contact us buttton. I am using ng-dialog
Here is my code which i am using.

home.html

On click of this contact US button i need a popup window.My popup is coming but it is not displaying data of contact_us template.

```
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
             <button type="button"  class="form-control" ng-click="openContactForm()">ContactUS</button>
             </div>

        home.js
        This is my javascript class.

        var app= angular.module('myApp',['ngDialog']);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,ngDialog){

            $scope.openContactForm = function() {
                ngDialog.open({
    template: 'contact_us.html',
     className : 'ngdialog-theme-default',
    plain: true,
    scope: $scope
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PHSS.png)

```
            };
        });

        Template which i want to display on click on contact us button

        Contact_us.html

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Contact us<h2>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" ng-model="mobile" />
            <textarea placeholder="Enter your message or query..." ng-model="message"></textarea>
            <div class="ngdialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-secondary" ng-click=closeThisDialog("Cancel")>Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click=confirm("OK")>OK</button>
                </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: it should be templateUrl instead of template and make sure url is correct

Comment: No it didn't work...

Comment: See the error in console

Comment: In **$scope.openContactForm** function change **template: 'contact_us.html',** to **templateUrl: 'contact_us.html',**

Comment: no ,i tried this still it is not working.

Comment: no error is there in console as well as

Answer (score 0):

Change plain to false for templates in file.

ngDialog.open({

```
template: 'contact_us.html',

className : 'ngdialog-theme-default',

plain: false,

scope: $scope
```

});

Also it is possible to use a simple string as template together with plain option.